# How to conditionally rename or exchange a table?

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-client

Is there an equivalent to the [T-SQL `IF...ELSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) keywords for control flow?

I'm trying to conditionally `EXCHANGE` tables `A` and `B` if `A` exists, otherwise just rename `B` to `A`. From documentation, all I'm seeing around conditional logic is to use functions within a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: ugly hack with clickhouse-client
```
clichouse-client -q "SELECT concat('EXCHANGE TABLES ',database,'.',name,' AND db1.table_B') FROM system.tables WHERE database='old_db' AND name='table_A' FORMAT TabSeparatedRaw" | clickhouse-client -q 
```

but this is not transactional safe